# Why would you place dependency in peer and dev?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, package.json, monorepo

I was wondering why one would put react and react-dom inside peerDependencies but also under devDependencies?

Is a peerDependency not enough for development?

Like seen here: https://github.com/belgattitude/nextjs-monorepo-example/blob/main/packages/core-lib/package.json

Edit: It is a Monorepo with React installed as a dependency in one of the projects, so I React should be installed, see https://github.com/belgattitude/nextjs-monorepo-example/blob/02955bbce36d2c06e5eb103eb1b09177f59c7782/apps/nextjs-app/package.json#L98

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
```

Answer (score -2):

To resolve the duplication of React and React DOM in both devDependencies and peerDependencies, you can remove them from devDependencies. Since they are already listed as peerDependencies, it indicates that the package expects consumers to have React and React DOM installed. By removing them from devDependencies, you ensure that during development, the package relies on the versions of React and React DOM installed by the consuming application. This simplifies the development setup, avoids version conflicts, and maintains consistency between development and production environments.

Comment: During development of the package, there _is_ no consuming application. That's why React is in both - you need it to _develop_ the package and to _consume_ it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was not totally clear, I am talking about a Monorepo with consumers that include React as a dep (so it is installed when you run dev)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).